# Creating Hierarchical Task Analysis tree

Tags: windows, gratis

I am looking for a software that would help me create a [Hierarchical Task Analysis tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_analysis#Hierarchical_Task_Analysis) similar to this

[image: HTA]

It has to be freeware. Online or offline does not really matter as long as the offline version runs on Windows.

Comment: Does the result have to look exactly like the example diagram, or would an [outline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_(list)) or a [mindmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) format work as well?

Comment: @Timmy If possible I would prefer to be more or less similar to the example

Comment: Would something like [this](http://imgur.com/y47Dxap.png) be similar enough?

Comment: Nope. It must be in a top down way. As this is for an assignment and not for personal or professional use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Google's Powerpoint. It is not specialized for creating HTA trees but I can manually create what I want. Either top to down or left to right. Basically any drawing tool can do the trick. It is not specialized for this case but it can provide manual drawing of what you want

Answer (score 0):

[TaskArchitect](http://www.taskarchitect.com) is designed to produce a task hierarchy quickly and easily, and will export a top-down or left-right view as a jpeg file for your report.

They offer a free version that can handle up to 20 tasks.  More than that, and you will have to buy the full version.

A 90% student discount is also available.

*Reviewer's note: This answer was originally written in a way that made it sound like the poster works for TaskArchitect.  No disclosure was made.  As such, this answer was edited and this note was added.  Furthermore, a question to the original poster regarding their affiliation with TaskArchitect will be posed.*

Comment: This is not a place to promote your software. You can write what it does and that's it, no ads, no links. Promoting explicitly is not allowed. Giving a suggestion and recommendation is what this Q&A is all about. I edited your answer to reflect that

Comment: David, please disclose any affiliation you have with TaskArchitect.